# Bug on installing plugin in opencart extension installer

Tags: php, ftp, opencart

On installing rest API in extension installer, got the warning as enable FTP.After enabling the FTP with necessary information, getting warning as

```
SyntaxError:Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0    
Ok    
<b>Warning</>:ftp_chdir();Failed to change directory. in <b>/var/www/html/admin/controller/extension/installer.php</b> on line<b>298</b>{"error":"Could not set root directory as"}
```

I have added FTP root as public_html/ and I have transferred the opencart upload folder to /var/www/html.
Is FTP root is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Well if your root folder is called just "html" why have you set it to "public_html"?

The FTP root is what appears in "Remote site:" when you log in with those FTP details in Filezilla for example:

[image]

So in your case, it may be "/html/" and notice that you should add the trailing slash (/).

Comment: Great, if your FTP account goes to the root of your website then yes / will work.

Comment: After installing the plugin, unable to use API.Getting error as
 Not Found
 The requested URL /api/rest was not found on this server.
Whats wrong with the url 'domain/api/rest/cart'?

Comment: Have you enabled SEO URLs and renamed .htaccess.txt to .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, its done. I have rewrite the rules in the htaccess file.Then it works fine.